# C# WPF - Problem changing color of image in realtime

Tags: c#, wpf, image-processing, image-manipulation

I'm having some problems changing the color of images in realtime. My vision is that the user of my main project should be able to adjust the colors by adjusting 3 sliders for RGB channels.

I found a good algorithm that does the job perfectly but the problem I'm facing now is that the color will only change once in the application. But on disk I can see the color changing.

Another potential problem is that saving the image to disk each time the color changes could be a performance issue (especially when dragging sliders in a quick manner), so I was hoping it was possible to load the converted image to a control like a button directly from the objec/memory.

I have set up a sample application for demonstration purposes. In the application I only change the Red channel by entering a value in a textbox. The other channels have been predefined in the code.

Any help with with this is highly appreciated since I've been struggling with this task for almost a week now.

First value with 0 on Red channel shows fine
[image: First value with 0 on Red channel shows fine]

Second value with 255 should have changed the image to yellow color but does not
[image: Second value with 255 should have changed the image to yellow color but does not]

Image is updated when I have it opened in the Photos app
[image: Image is updated when I have it opened in the Photos app]

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using Point = System.Drawing.Point;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using Image = System.Drawing.Image;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using Rectangle = System.Drawing.Rectangle;
using System.Threading;

namespace ImageColorConversionTesting
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            byte number;

            if(System.Byte.TryParse(NumberTextBox.Text, out number))
            {

                LoadImage(number);

            }

        }

        private void LoadImage(byte redcolor)
        {
            Bitmap newImage = ConvertImageColor(255, redcolor, 255, 0, @"Images\house-64.png");
            newImage.Save("test.png");
            System.Windows.Controls.Image imgHome = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
            imgHome.Source = BitmapFromUri(new Uri("test.png", UriKind.Relative));
           
            image3.Source = imgHome.Source;

        }

        public Bitmap ConvertImageColor(int alpha, int red, int green, int blue, string filename)
        {
            System.Drawing.Color newColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(alpha, red, green, blue);
            Image originalImage = Image.FromFile(filename);
            Bitmap newImage = ToColorTone(originalImage, newColor);

            return newImage;

        }

        private Bitmap ToColorTone(Image image, System.Drawing.Color color)
        {

            int brightness = color.A;
            float scale = brightness;

            float r = color.R / 255f * scale;
            float g = color.G / 255f * scale;
            float b = color.B / 255f * scale;

   
            ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[][]
            {
                new float[] {r, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                new float[] {0, g, 0, 0, 0},
                new float[] {0, 0, b, 0, 0},
                new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
            });

            ImageAttributes ImAttribute = new ImageAttributes();
            ImAttribute.SetColorMatrix(cm);

          
            Point[] points =
            {
                new Point(0, 0),
                new Point(image.Width - 1, 0),
                new Point(0, image.Height - 1),
            };
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);

            Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);
            using(Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap))
            {
                graphics.DrawImage(image, points, rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ImAttribute);
            }
            return myBitmap;
        }

        public static System.Windows.Media.ImageSource BitmapFromUri(Uri source)
        {
            var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.UriSource = source;
            bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmap.EndInit();
            return bitmap;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing and reading an image file at all, instead of directly manipulating the colors (either pixel values or color palette entries) of a BitmapSource in memory?

Comment: Because I don't know how, I'm a pretty fresh programmer. I simply searched for solutions on the web and found an algorithm that worked.

Comment: That's not the right approach. Take a look at the BitmapSource class, maybe also WriteableBitmap. Make yourself familiar with how to create a BitmapSource from an existing pixel buffer by one of the static Create methods of the BitmapSource class.

Comment: Are you sure you really need to manipulate bitmaps at all? Maybe you can just change the Fill Brush of a drawing in a Path element.

Comment: I will try with the BitmapSource class. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code you provided, the reason why the image does not refresh is the cache of `BitmapImage`.

In the official document of [BitmapImage.CreateOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage.createoptions?view=winrt-22000), it says:

> The other possible value for CreateOptions is BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache. You should only use BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache in cases where you know that the source image file as retrieved by Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) has the potential to change over time.

After changing the `CreateOptions`, it works well.

```
public static System.Windows.Media.ImageSource BitmapFromUri(Uri source)
{
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    bitmap.BeginInit();
    bitmap.UriSource = source;
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    // NOTE: ignore the image cache
    bitmap.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
    bitmap.EndInit();
    return bitmap;
}
```

As other friends' recommandation, use `BitmapSource` is a better implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I already resolved the issue using BitmapSource as suggested earlier by Clemens.